# recognising two equations are in the same form (basic)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

I have the function $f(x)$ satisfies: $$4x^2f'' + 4xf' + (a^2x-v)f = 0$$

I have now just found the function $X(x)$ satisfies the equation $$\dfrac{d}{dx}(x \dfrac{dX}{dx}) + \dfrac{\lambda}{g}X = 0$$  my text says that these not are equivalent, if I set $a =  2 \sqrt{\lambda/g}$ and $v = 0$. However, I don't see the equivalence, the second equation seems to be missing an $x$ term from the leading coefficient... please help

Comment: Mutliply second equation by $4x$ and set parameters $a$ and $v$ as mentioned

Comment: but why can we multiple by $x$, there is a chance x can be 0?

Comment: It's clear that with appropriate $a$ and $v$, the second equation implies the first one simply by multiplying $4x$. To show the equivalence, we need to also show that first one implies the second one, but as long as $x$ is not $0$ this is true. In general, in differential equations you are not interested in difference in null sets (lebesgue measure $0$) because they can be pretty much considered the same function, and you usually solve DE's by integrating, which usually only identifies functions up to almost everywhere equality, so one point difference does not matter much

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with the first equation, we have $$4x^2f'' + 4xf' + (\frac{4x\lambda}{g})f = 0$$ after setting a = $2\sqrt\frac{\lambda}{g}$ and v = 0. Now, the second equation using the product rule becomes: $$x\frac{d^2X}{dx^2} + \frac{dX}{dx} + \frac{\lambda}{g}X = 0$$

Now, multiply the second equation by 4x to get the following: 
$$4x^2\frac{d^2X}{dx^2} + 4x\frac{dX}{dx} + \frac{4x\lambda}{g}X = 0$$
and the equivalence is manifest.